# Magento 1.9 - Observer Event redirection issue after placing order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, redirect

This is my xml :

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <test_magewidget_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Test_MageWidget_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>testRedirection</method>
                </test_magewidget_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

This is my Observer :

```
class Test_MageWidget_Model_Observer {

    public function testRedirection($observer) {
        try {
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("checkout/cart"));
            Mage::log('Hi', null, 'magewidget.log');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

After placing order event being triggered, but redirection not working properly. It's showing in Browser network response, but not reflecting on the browser.

What can be the reason behind this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
public function testRedirection($observer) {
    Mage::log('Hi', null, 'magewidget.log', true); 
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'))->sendResponse();            
}
```

Comment: Hi Prince, Thanks for your help but still having the same issue.